# What colon ( : ) means defining a class in c#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

In c# defining a class what does `:` means?

As example, in this very basic controller of an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
namespace App.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {    
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

In the third line, what does `: Controller` means?

Comment: I think it denotes that `HomeController` inherits from `Controller`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In this case it means that the `HomeController` inherits the `Controller` class.

You can read more details about inheritance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx), but simply put - inheritance means that everything a `Controller` is, a `HomeController` is also.  A `HomeController` is a more finely grained `Controller` class.

It can also be used for implementation of interfaces http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Answer (score 14):

The `:` is used in C# to denote class inheritance or interface implementation.  In this case `HomeController` inherits from the class `Controller`

Comment: So essentially it will have the same objects in it and do the same stuff?